# Jquery textfield make my fuction activated after I input in the jquery field - how to call a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

html and javascript. I would like to ask for advice I am trying to implement a function in my jquery textfield however its not working. the code I am using works perfectly if I am creating a textfield in html but its not working if I use my jquery textfield

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onblur="myFunction()">

<p>When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my code when I apply jquery try is the id of my textfield jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

        <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#try").on( function () {
   myFunction();
});
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("try").value;
                    document.getElementById("try").value = "hi" + x ;

}
        </script>




</html>
```

Comment: mark your answer of your question as accepted, Below those answers are all fine for your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onblur="myFunction()">
<div id="try">

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#fname").on("keyup", function () {
        myFunction();
    });
});
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "hi " + x;
}    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because myFunction Attached before event myFunction declared

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bj85dwe7/7/)

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="fname" onblur="myFunction()">
```

this is your Example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/uwj9Lzna/)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the focusout event and then a toUpperCase on the .val

```js
$('#fname').on('focusout',  function() {  
   $(this).val(`hi ${$(this).val().toUpperCase()}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname">

<p>When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.</p>
```